# How to insert JSON Data into form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form consist of `dropdown` and `input fields` some fields are read only.
What I am trying to do is to store the JSON data inside the form fields

here I have

- Distributor name (dropdown)
- Name of the user (dropdown)
- user Code (input field)
- Login Id (input field)
- password (input field)

I Have JSON as

```
    [
  {
    "Distributor": "maiyas",
    "Name": "admin",
    "User Code": "AAA01",
    "Login Id": "admin123",
    "password": "admin123"
  }
]
```

**snippet**

```js
function show(a) {
  var x = document.getElementById(a);
  var c = x.nextElementSibling
  if (x.getAttribute('type') == "password") {
    c.removeAttribute("class");
    c.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-eye");
    x.removeAttribute("type");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
  } else {
    x.removeAttribute("type");
    x.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    c.removeAttribute("class");
    c.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-eye-slash");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testingForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Distributor Name</h5>
        <select id="myselect"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Name Of the user</h5>
        <select id="myselect"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">User Code</h5>
        <input type="text" id="userCode" name="usercode" class="commanClass" placeholder="user Code" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Login Id</h5>
        <input type="text" id="loginId" name="loginid" class="commanClass" placeholder="Login Id" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
        <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password" readonly="readonly"> <i onclick="show('currentPass')" class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="display"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

I am getting JSON object inside a array and want to display the JSON data into fields.

Comment: use the `setAttribute` similar to set the "value" attribute of any input and for most inputs that will work to show it in the html. good luck

Comment: @Tope can you help me with some code please

Comment: @dheerajkumar, See the answer I have posted and take a look at the comments also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var resultJSONWithOneItem =  [
  {
    "Distributor": "maiyas",
    "Name": "admin",
    "User Code": "AAA01",
    "Login Id": "admin123",
    "password": "admin123"
   }
];

var resultJSONArray =  [
  {
    "Distributor": "maiyas",
    "Name": "admin",
    "User Code": "AAA01",
    "Login Id": "admin123",
    "password": "admin123"
  },
  {
    "Distributor": "maiyas_1",
    "Name": "admin_1",
    "User Code": "AAA01_1",
    "Login Id": "admin123_1",
    "password": "admin123_1"
  }, 
  {
    "Distributor": "maiyas_2",
    "Name": "admin_2",
    "User Code": "AAA01_2",
    "Login Id": "admin123_2",
    "password": "admin123_2"
  }
];
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    $('#myselect').val(resultJSONWithOneItem[0]['Distributor']);
    $('#userCode').val(resultJSONWithOneItem[0]['User Code']);
    $('#loginId').val(resultJSONWithOneItem[0]['Login Id']);
    $('#currentPass').val(resultJSONWithOneItem[0]['password']);  
    
    //If there was multi items for your drop down you can iterate them
    var s = $('#myselect');
    for (var i = 0; i <= resultJSONArray.length - 1; i++) {
    $('<option />', {
     value: resultJSONArray[i].Distributor, text: resultJSONArray[i].Distributor
    }).appendTo(s);
  } 
        //Set your expect value to drop down like $('#dropName').val('an item in drop down list');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testingForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Distributor Name</h5>
        <select id="myselect"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Name Of the user</h5>
        <select id="myselect"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">User Code</h5>
        <input type="text" id="userCode" name="usercode" class="commanClass" placeholder="user Code" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Login Id</h5>
        <input type="text" id="loginId" name="loginid" class="commanClass" placeholder="Login Id" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
        <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password" readonly="readonly"> <i onclick="show('currentPass')" class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="display"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Notes:
1- From what I can see your JSON item's properties have space so you can not access JSON item property like `resultJSONWithOneItem[0].PropertyName` so you should access props by index like `resultJSONWithOneItem[0]['User Code']`.
2- If there are array more than one item like `resultJSONArray` you should iterate JSON for your DropDown element and add `option` to it at then select your expected value like `

```
 //If there was mulyi items for your drop down you can iterate them
 var s = $('#myselect');
 for (var i = 0; i <= resultJSONArray.length - 1; i++) {
      $('<option />', {
            value: resultJSONArray[i].Distributor, text: resultJSONArray[i].Distributor
        }).appendTo(s);
 } 
 //s.val(resultJSONArray[0]['Distributer']);
```

3- you defined two `DropDown`s with one unique ID as `mySelect` which is not correct in HTML.

Comment: hey thanx this is what i was looking for

Comment: @dheerajkumar, You are welcome, you can play with codes and improve it as you want, but good this gave you the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you really want - I guess something like following code.

1. JSON data is now an object instead of an array of objects.
2. Form field names are now equal to keys of JSON data.
3. Selects have options including what is in JSON data.

function fillJsonData() is what you want.

Anyway, I hope the password is not a saved password. Never save a password as plain text.

```js
function fillJsonData () {
    var jsonData =
    {
        "Distributor": "maiyas",
        "Name": "admin",
        "UserCode": "AAA01",
        "LoginId": "admin123",
        "password": "admin123"
    };


    for (var key in jsonData) {
        $("#testingForm").find('[name="'+key+'"]').val(jsonData[key]);
    }
}

function show(a) {
  var x = document.getElementById(a);
  var c = x.nextElementSibling
  if (x.getAttribute('type') == "password") {
    c.removeAttribute("class");
    c.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-eye");
    x.removeAttribute("type");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
  } else {
    x.removeAttribute("type");
    x.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    c.removeAttribute("class");
    c.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-eye-slash");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="fillJsonData(); return false;" href="#">click me for fill form</a>
<form id="testingForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Distributor Name</h5>
        <select name="Distributor" id="myselect">
            <option value="">..</option>
            <option value="foo">foo</option>
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
            <option value="maiyas">maiyas</option>
            <option value="admin">admin</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Name Of the user</h5>
        <select name="Name" id="myselect">
            <option value="">..</option>
            <option value="foo">foo</option>
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
            <option value="maiyas">maiyas</option>
            <option value="admin">admin</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">User Code</h5>
        <input type="text" id="userCode" name="UserCode" class="commanClass" placeholder="user Code" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Login Id</h5>
        <input type="text" id="LoginId" name="LoginId" class="commanClass" placeholder="Login Id" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
        <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="password" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password" readonly="readonly"> <i onclick="show('currentPass')" class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="display"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```